Clicking add button on the UI adding a new column in mySQL
When I am clicking a add button on the UI, how the backend will add a new column in the mySQL table? I am using React and Express. Tried chatGPT but it isn't populating the UI.
const [crushersCount, setCrushersCount] = useState(0);

const handleAddCrusher = async () => {
    try {

      const response = await fetch('/add-crusher-columns', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ count: 1 }) 
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to add column');
        
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data.message);

      setCrushersCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

// UI
<tr>

      <td >6.1. No. of Crushers:</td>
      <td>
        <button onClick={handleAddCrusher} className="add_more_button">
          Add
        </button>
      </td>
</tr>
      {[...Array(crushersCount)].map((_, index) => (
        <tr key={`crusher_${index}`}>
          <td>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name={`crusher_${index}_type`}
              value="fixed"
              checked={formData[`crusher_${index}_type`] === "fixed"}
              onChange={handleChange}
              />
            Fixed 
            <input
              type="radio"
              name={`crusher_${index}_type`}
              value="mobile"
              checked={formData[`crusher_${index}_type`] === "mobile"}
              onChange={handleChange}
              />
            Mobile 
            
          </td>
          <td>
          
            <input
              type="number"
              name={`crusher_${index}_input`}
              value={formData[`crusher_${index}_input`]}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder={`Crusher ${index + 1} Capacity `} 
              />
            <button
              onClick={() => handleRemoveCrusher(index)}
              className="remove_button"
              >
              Remove
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
  

// SERVER
app.post('/add-crusher-columns', (req, res) => {
  const { count } = req.body;

  
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const columnType = 'VARCHAR(255)'; 

    
    const columnTypeColumnName = `crusher_${i}_type`;
    const columnInputColumnName = `crusher_${i}_input`;

    
    const sqlType = `ALTER TABLE mines_info ADD COLUMN ${columnTypeColumnName} ${columnType}`;
    const sqlInput = `ALTER TABLE mines_info ADD COLUMN ${columnInputColumnName} ${columnType}`;


    connection.query(sqlType, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error adding type column:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        return;
      }
      console.log(`Type column ${columnTypeColumnName} added successfully`);
    });

    connection.query(sqlInput, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error adding input column:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        return;
      }
      console.log(`Input column ${columnInputColumnName} added successfully`);
    });
  }

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Columns added successfully' });
});

Tried chatGPT but 1 it isn't populating the UI neither the SQL

You can tell if you are seeing any error messages in your client or server consoles.
